when we put html code in angular 16 project for image uploading
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)ngtsc(-995002)




@if (progress) {
  <mat-toolbar class="progress-bar">
    <mat-progress-bar color="accent" [value]="progress"></mat-progress-bar>
    <span class="progress">{{ progress }}%</span>
  </mat-toolbar>
  }

  <mat-form-field>
    <div>
      <mat-toolbar>
        <input matInput [value]="fileName" />

        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="!currentFile" (click)="upload()">
          Upload
        </button>
      </mat-toolbar>

      <input type="file" id="fileInput" (change)="selectFile($event)" name="fileInput" />
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

@if (message) {
<div class="message">
  {{ message }}
</div>
}

<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>List of Files</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-list role="list">
      @for (file of fileInfos | async; track file.name) {
      <mat-list-item role="listitem">
        <a href="{{ file.url }}">{{ file.name }}</a>
      </mat-list-item>
      }
    </mat-list>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>


error shown when we copy paste this material angular html code but error shown as
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)ngtsc(-995002)
file-upload.component.ts(10, 74): Error occurs in the template of component FileUploadComponent.
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'.ngtsc(-995002)
